# How can I remove standard windows menu in JavaFX app?

Tags: java, menu, javafx, sandbox

I need simple frame without borders and top menu, is it possible?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is off-topic? Sure there might be missing some code. But as you can see in the answer, there is not much code left to show. Except from the line to hide the standard menu, it is a default JavaFX application. How should he ask his question instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming by "top menu" you mean the title bar and platform decorations (typically minimize, maximize, and close buttons).

Simply call `Stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class UndecoratedStageExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("OK");
        button.setOnAction(event -> primaryStage.close());
        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 80);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```